# Unable to import json file to mLab databse - assertion: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am trying to import my json file to my newly created mLab database.

I used the command

```
mongoimport -h ds041526.mlab.com:41526 -d coursera_zips -c zips -u %MONGO_USER% -p %MONGO_PASSWORD% --file db/zips.json
```

I know that the username and password I entered are correct, yet I still get the error telling me I failed to authenticate. Not sure why.

Comment: what version of `mongoimport`? You're likely not running a version that supports SCRAM-SHA-1 auth if you're certain the username & password are correct. Best to use a version that matches (at least closely) the version of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the `authenticationDatabase`  option for mongo import along with user name and passport.

```
mongoimport -h ds041526.mlab.com:41526 -d coursera_zips -c zips -u %MONGO_USER% -p %MONGO_PASSWORD%  --authenticationDatabase %AUTH_DB% --file db/zips.json
```